# Persistent directory stacks across sessions in zsh

Tags: zsh, command-history, pushd

I would like to share my directory stack (the one accessed with `dirs`) across sessions and tmux panes/windows.

In the [`zshbuiltins` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/zshbuiltins) I have found `autopushd` to add every directory I switch into to the stack. But there does not seem to be a native way to have the stack persist and share it.

Do I have to save the stack to a temporary file or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, this is not a good idea. Consider this scenario:

1. Session one wants to temporarily change directories, so it pushes the current directory, expecting to pop it later when it is finished with the new directory.
2. Session two tries the same thing.
3. Session one tries to pop its original directory off the stack, but gets session two's directory instead.

This doesn't really answer your question, but I'm trying to illustrate *why* there is no native method for doing so. For a one-time "export" of the stack from one session to another, your best bet is writing to a temp file and reading it back in, but there isn't going to be a general method for keeping the stack in sync among multiple sessions.

Comment: You are right, there are too many possible conflicts and exceptions to consider. In the meantime I found a great utility ([z](https://github.com/rupa/z)) that allows for fast directory switching by partial string matching. Thanks.

Comment: I think this is too narrow of an outlook on this problem. Other related concepts in zsh support the concept of saving history to a specific session, such as `setopt INC_APPEND_HISTORY_TIME`

Comment: The directory stack is intimately tied to the idea of the current working directory, which is unique to each process. History of the commands executed in the shell is not part of the *state* of a shell session, just a log.